# Stuck in flexbox! making responsive image gallery

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I have images of different **width** and **height**. And I am trying to make responsive image gallery. I am only able to create responsive image gallery if I first make all the images of same dimension using online-tool. But I don't want to do that. That's not a good way to do that, I think.
I have created these two code snippets. I want my *media query breakpoints at* **860px, 640px**.These break points are must.

**CODE SNIPPET 1ST**

> Every things is as I wanted except image heights. I want them to be equal without affecting other things. I have created another code snippets to take of that height, but now it is messing everything around. See **second code snippet** after you review this one.

```css
.container {
  background: rgb(69, 86, 125);
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  
}
.img-wrapper {
 margin: 20px 10px;
  width: 30%;
  
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.img-wrapper p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: cursive;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;

}
@media screen and (max-width: 860px)
{
  .container {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
  }
  .img-wrapper {
    width: 45%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px)
{
  .container {
    background-color: #1f996a;
    
  }
  .img-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/mUUnWsw1UC_5YLXBC5OT5-Sgt5B_j_AhOeyv1zDRlfe3rwrjuuT3NoS1rdqIU_LA896JGqdaiQIUfb_EQw10MRl4QE-uT5vS79uqy58XrcP-7BW622XXdg" alt="">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.eso.org/public/archives/images/screen/8k-4k-hd_comparison.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://www.wallpapertip.com/wmimgs/11-118446_nice-wallpapers-15-bb-q5.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
   <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTs8Kf7l4F4FYhMh7O9eOLX3ny5RBdIdn3ckmEIjleiOo9BEU47Lmpia5XVkUipxGjfIHY&usqp=CAU" alt="">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://st1.bollywoodlife.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/FotoJet-2021-06-06T215523.686.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a9/df/32/a9df3251b065a7593481c886601f2895.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

**CODE SNIPPET SECOND**

> Now I have created images to be same height which I wanted, but now it is messing with responsiveness. Since they are now of **fixed rigid pixel**, they are not shrinking as in code snippet first. Help me !

```css
.container {
  background: rgb(69, 86, 125);
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  
}
.wrapper {
  margin: 20px 10px;
}
.img-wrapper {
 
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.img-wrapper p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: cursive;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 860px)
{
  .container {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: 45%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px)
{
  .container {
    background-color: #1f996a;
    
  }
  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/mUUnWsw1UC_5YLXBC5OT5-Sgt5B_j_AhOeyv1zDRlfe3rwrjuuT3NoS1rdqIU_LA896JGqdaiQIUfb_EQw10MRl4QE-uT5vS79uqy58XrcP-7BW622XXdg" alt="">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.eso.org/public/archives/images/screen/8k-4k-hd_comparison.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://www.wallpapertip.com/wmimgs/11-118446_nice-wallpapers-15-bb-q5.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTs8Kf7l4F4FYhMh7O9eOLX3ny5RBdIdn3ckmEIjleiOo9BEU47Lmpia5XVkUipxGjfIHY&usqp=CAU" alt="">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://st1.bollywoodlife.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/FotoJet-2021-06-06T215523.686.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a9/df/32/a9df3251b065a7593481c886601f2895.jpg" alt="">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used your media query for 640px screen, but changed `.wrapper` class to `.img-wrapper`. Now it's responsive on mobile.

```css
.container {
  background: rgb(69, 86, 125);
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.img-wrapper {
  margin: 20px 10px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 400px; /* New line */

  border: 2px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.img-wrapper p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: cursive;
  margin-top: -3px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 62px); /* Edited line */
  object-fit: cover;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
  .container {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
  }
  .img-wrapper {
    width: 45%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  .container {
    background-color: #1f996a;
  }
  .img-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img
          src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/mUUnWsw1UC_5YLXBC5OT5-Sgt5B_j_AhOeyv1zDRlfe3rwrjuuT3NoS1rdqIU_LA896JGqdaiQIUfb_EQw10MRl4QE-uT5vS79uqy58XrcP-7BW622XXdg"
          alt=""
        />
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img
          src="http://www.eso.org/public/archives/images/screen/8k-4k-hd_comparison.jpg"
          alt=""
        />
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img
          src="https://www.wallpapertip.com/wmimgs/11-118446_nice-wallpapers-15-bb-q5.jpg"
          alt=""
        />
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img
          src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTs8Kf7l4F4FYhMh7O9eOLX3ny5RBdIdn3ckmEIjleiOo9BEU47Lmpia5XVkUipxGjfIHY&usqp=CAU"
          alt=""
        />
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img
          src="https://st1.bollywoodlife.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/FotoJet-2021-06-06T215523.686.jpg"
          alt=""
        />
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
      <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img
          src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/a9/df/32/a9df3251b065a7593481c886601f2895.jpg"
          alt=""
        />
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my problem properly. I have two code snippets. The first one is what I wanted but due to the images of different heights, it is not looking good. But everything else is good on that. In the second code snippets, I have made the images to be of fixed width i.e used fixed to make images to be equal size but now since that becomes images of rigid size, my  resonsiveness is having trouble. It is not shrinking. How do I make images to be shrinking until they reach the 860px break point and lay two column only.

Comment: Now i understood, for solution that issue just put height in `.img-wrapper` class. I guess this help. I did update snippet.

Comment: Also did update for image height, for fit text  inside `.img-wrapper`.

Comment: Never thought on that. I just had to use **height** in img-wrapper for getting what I wanted. It was so simple yet I was feeling so overwhelmed. I don't know why I didn't thought that. Thank you so much. Is there a way that I can be in touch with you? You are my life-savior.